# display content of [object HTMLDivElement]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My goal is to display input field and span right next to it. To achieve this I generate two divs inside a parent one (two "small-6 columns" inside "row" from foundation framework).

If I go for .appendChild(el) and .appendChild(span) it works. When I want to put the divs in work I get [object HTMLDivElement][object HTMLDivElement] printed as result.

I have tried $(ldiv).html() and many variations, but I just cant figure it out.

Thank you for response

```
var cellRight = row.insertCell(1);
          var div = document.createElement('div');
          div.class = 'row';
          //
          var el = document.createElement('input');
          el.type = 'text';
          el.name = 'produkty_mnozstvi_jednotek' + iteration;
          el.id = 'produkty_mnozstvi_jednotek' + iteration;
          el.style.width = '3.5rem';
          //
          var ldiv = document.createElement('div');
          ldiv.class = 'small-6 columns';
          ldiv.id = 'ldiv' + iteration;
          ldiv.innerHTML = el;
          //
          var span = document.createElement('span');
          span.id = 'naskladneni_mnozstvi_jednotek' + iteration;
          //
          var rdiv = document.createElement('div');
          rdiv.class = 'small-6 columns';
          rdiv.id = 'rdiv' + iteration;
          rdiv.innerHTML = span;
          //
          div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + ldiv + rdiv; 
          //
          cellRight.appendChild(div);
          //cellRight.appendChild(el);
          //cellRight.appendChild(span); //works fine but divs are ignored and span in under the input, not next to it (workaround)
```

Comment: shouldn't this be `div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + ldiv.innerHTML  + rdiv.innerHTML ; ` ?

Comment: it slightly changes the printed result into [object HTMLInputElement][object HTMLSpanElement]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found solution in correct use of appendChild()

```
var tbl = document.getElementById('tblProdukty');
          var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
          var iteration = lastRow;
          var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

          // left cell
          var cellLeft = row.insertCell(0);
          var textNode = document.createTextNode(iteration);
          cellLeft.appendChild(textNode);

          // jednotka bunka
          var cellRight = row.insertCell(1);
          var div = document.createElement('div');
          div.class = 'row';
          //
          var el = document.createElement('input');
          el.type = 'text';
          el.name = 'objednavka_mnozstvi_jednotek' + iteration;
          el.id = 'objednavka_mnozstvi_jednotek' + iteration;
          el.style.width = '3.5rem';
          //
          var ldiv = document.createElement('div');
          ldiv.class = 'small-6 columns';
          ldiv.id = 'ldiv' + iteration;
          ldiv.appendChild(el);
          //
          var span = document.createElement('span');
          span.name = 'naskladneni_mnozstvi_jednotek' + iteration;
          span.id = 'naskladneni_mnozstvi_jednotek' + iteration;
          //
          var rdiv = document.createElement('div');
          rdiv.class = 'small-6 columns';
          rdiv.id = 'rdiv' + iteration;
          rdiv.appendChild(span);
          //
          div.appendChild(ldiv);
          div.appendChild(rdiv);
          //
          cellRight.appendChild(div);
```

Answer (score 7):

Use appendChild instead of innerHTML. Maybe it helps you:

```
function run() {
  var row = document.getElementById('row');
  var cellRight = row.insertCell();
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.class = 'row';

  var el = document.createElement('input');
  el.type = 'text';
  el.name = 'produkty_mnozstvi_jednotek' + iteration;
  el.id = 'produkty_mnozstvi_jednotek' + iteration;
  el.style.width = '3.5rem';
  //
  var el = document.createElement('input');
  el.type = 'text';
  el.name = 'produkty_mnozstvi_jednotek' + iteration;
  el.id = 'produkty_mnozstvi_jednotek' + iteration;
  el.style.width = '3.5rem';
  //
  var ldiv = document.createElement('div');
  ldiv.class = 'small-6 columns';
  ldiv.id = 'ldiv' + iteration;
  ldiv.appendChild(el);
  //
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.id = 'naskladneni_mnozstvi_jednotek' + iteration;
  //
  var rdiv = document.createElement('div');
  rdiv.class = 'small-6 columns';
  rdiv.id = 'rdiv' + iteration;
  rdiv.appendChild(span);
  //
  div.appendChild(ldiv);
  div.appendChild(rdiv);
  cellRight.appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: this results in same situation like cellRight.appendChild(el) cellRight.appendChild(div) ... it ignores the parent/child relation of divs